# How to make protocol only usable by certain classes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, protocols

Im making a protocol but I only want it to be implementable by `View Controllers`. Im doing this to keep the code consistent and to try and avoid confusion for someone new to the project.

I was also wondering if by making a protocol only extendable by a `UIViewController` would I be able to access the `UIViewControllers` variables?

Answer (score 3):

```
protocol P where Self: UIViewControlller {

}
```